# search for an artifact in artifactory using curl

Tags: devops, artifactory, jfrog-container-registry

I read the REST api again and again but couldn't figure out the exact syntax of how to search for an artifact in the artifactory using curl.

This is what I am doing:

```
result=$(curl -u ${ArtifactoryUsername}:${ArtifactoryAPIKey} -X GET "${artifactory_repo}/api/search/artifact?name=${generated_package_name}")
echo "${result}"
```

Here, artifactory_repo is

```
https://xxx.artifactory.xxx.com:443/artifactory/hyc-ca-container-helm-local
```

and *hyc-ca-container-helm-local* is my repo which I already appended on the end of my artifactory url

The file is there in the artifactory but I am getting the message file not found.
I am sure the reason is that the syntax I am using is incorrect.

Can anyone guide me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching for an artifact within a given repository (using the artifact search API), you should use the following format:

```
GET /api/search/artifact?name=lib&repos=libs-release-local
```

For the code you have n your question, it should be:

```
result=$(curl -u ${ArtifactoryUsername}:${ArtifactoryAPIKey} -X GET "https://xxx.artifactory.xxx.com:443/artifactory/api/search/artifact?name=${generated_package_name}&repos=hyc-ca-container-helm-local")
```

Notice that the repository name (hyc-ca-container-helm-local) should be provided as a query parameter and not as part of the URL. You have placed it before the api context which lead to the 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Artifactory Query Language](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactoryQueryLanguage(AQL)) (AQL) along with the REST API and do the search.